# How can I figure out which "side" of a line segment a ray is pointing towards?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Here is a drawing of the problem:

[image]

I have a ray sitting at *r_origin* and pointing towards *r_dir*. There's also a line segment *AB* with normal vectors *n1* and *n2*.

I need to find whether *n1* and *r_dir* point towards each other or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if n1.(r_dir) is positive or negative.

Comment: Does . mean dot product?

Comment: @AlexUndefined yes it means dot product, cosine of angle between vectors will decide if they point toward or away from each other

Comment: Thanks, that works.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).